Scoreboard: failed to lock
the error log for php 8.x, reports that there is an error.  It looks like this:
2024/08/15 17:55:10 [error] 1753#1753: *836069 FastCGI sent in stderr: "scoreboard: failed to lock (already locked); status: unable to find or access status shared memory" while reading response header from upstream, client: x.x.x.x, server: x.x.com, request: "GET /status?json&full HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/run/php/php8.3-fpm.sock:", host: "x.x.com"
for me - it looks like the potential solution is that my main website allows extended timeouts for php scripts.  Reducing the script times for the status page, seems to make this better.
I added this:
    location ~ ^/(status|ping)$ {
            proxy_read_timeout 5;
            proxy_send_timeout 5;
            proxy_connect_timeout 5;
            send_timeout 5;
            fastcgi_send_timeout 5;
            fastcgi_read_timeout 5;
            fastcgi_connect_timeout 5;
            client_max_body_size 128K;

            allow all;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            #fastcgi_index index.php;
            include fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php8.3-fpm.sock;
    }

which seems to have immediately removed the scoreboard issues that I have been battling with - and I have not been able to google a solution for it.

Apparently I was too quick to post. Still getting the issue.

I've never personally seen this error before, and there's not a whole heck of a lot of information on it either. Are you by any chance using Kubernetes or Docker? If so, are you utilizing either a Healthcheck or probe to check status? There seems to be some helpful information on this Github issue but it's hard to say without knowing the full scope of your setup. I'd also recommend posting in ServerFault, as you may get better answers there.

How much traffic are you sending over to the FPM? The scoreboard uses non-blocking locks for updates. Every pool has one scoreboard. I think under high concurrency locks are bound to start failing.

I resolved the issue by setting up a "gatekeeper" that cached the data every second.  To prevent race conditions - and it has seemed to resolve the issue.
